# How do I send log4perl log messages to Amazon Cloudwatch?

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, logging, log4perl, cloudwatch

I have a Perl/Plack/Postgres/Linux web application that runs on an Amazon EC2 instance. I'm about to start running it on multiple instances, behind a load balancer, so I need a way to gather together the application's log messages into a single place.

Currently I use a log4perl configuration file that uses Log::Log4perl::Appender::File to record the logs onto disk. Some log messages are routed to more than one log file and some are also handled by appenders that send email. I use the Linux logrotate utility for rotation, but I don't use syslog for application level messages at all.

Sending logs to Amazon Cloudwatch seems like it might be a good solution to the problem. Whilst I can find various modules on CPAN to interact with Amazon Cloudwatch (module suggestions appreciated), I can't find any ready-made log4perl appenders to assist with the problem. Do I need to write my own?

If it makes any difference, I already use AWS::Signature4 and Amazon::S3::Thin in my project. Thus far I have avoided modules with heavy dependencies, such as Moose, but I could relax that policy if necessary.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "awslogs" agent for EC2 instances. This would help to ship the logs to cloudwatch. The shipped logs would be available under the Logs section in cloudwatch console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awslogs if you meet the log requirements (good timestamp format for ex).  It will probably be a bit easier to setup if you are running Amazon Linux, but possible on most distros.

Read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html.